# Convert XML or DTD to C structure

Tags: c, xml, dtd

I have an XML file and corresponding DTD file. I need to have a C structure to store values from XML. Which one is better?

1. Convert XML to C structure?

or

2. Convert DTD to C structure?

and is there any library tool for this conversion instead of writing codes?

Comment: Sorry; not clear what you mean by your two choices, or how they would be different in practice.  And questions about which tool to use are explicitly out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: DTD is html which is harder to parse than xml so I would use xml.  If the xml has a schema there are toolos available to automatically create c classes from the schema.

Comment: Hello, Do you mean I should use an XSD for that? Can you suggest me name of  one library tool please?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking for is a tool that does [XML Data Binding](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-data-binder/what-is-xml-data-binding-part-1), i.e. creates an api/class library from the description of an XML document (DTD/XSD etc). There are a number of [XML Data Binding tools for C++](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-schema-to-cpp), but none that I am aware of that work for plain C.

If you don't have a schema there are a number of online tools that will infer one from an XML document. Most XML Data Binding tools require an XSD rather than a DTD schema though.